Why is VSCode not fetching the details that are given to the contract after the deployment to the Remix IDE?
Why is VSCode not fetching the details that are given to the contract after the deployment to the Remix IDE?
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import { FaDonate } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, Row, Button } from "reactstrap"
import projectImg from "../../assets/img1.png"
import "./Projects.css"

const Projects = ({state}) => {
    const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
    const [projects, setProjects] = useState("");
    useEffect(()=>{
        const {contract}=state;
        const projectDetails =async()=>{
            const projects = await contract.methods.allProjects().call();
            console.log(state)
            setProjects(projects)
        }
        contract && projectDetails();
    },[state]);
    return (
        <section className="project-section">
            <h1 className="title">Projects </h1>
            <div className="card-wrapper">
                {projects!=="" && projects.map((project)=>{
                    return ( <a href= "#" className="project-card" target='_blank' rel="noopener noreferrer" >
                    <div className="card-img">
                        <img src={`https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/${projects.image}`} alt="" /></div>
                    <div className="card-text">
                        <h3>{project.name}</h3>
                        <p>{project.description}</p>
                    </div>
                </a>)
                })} 
            </div>
 {/*  =========popup bootstrap==========  */}

<Modal size='md' isOpen={modal} toggle={() => setModal(!modal)}>
                        <ModalHeader toggle={() => setModal(!modal)}>
                            Enter the ETH you want to donate!
                        </ModalHeader>
                        <ModalBody>
                            <form >
                                <Row>
                                    <input id="eth" type="text" />
                                        <Button className='mt-4' >
                                            Send
                                        </Button>
                                </Row>
                            </form>
                        </ModalBody>
                    </Modal>
                    {/*  =========popup bootstrap end==========  */}
                    <p className='donate' onClick={() => setModal(true)}>Liked the dummyValue's ? Consider donating Eth's <FaDonate className='icon' /></p>
        </section>
    )
}

export default Projects

